# Sending Multipart Email in vbscript

Tags: email, vbscript, mime, multipart

I wrote a script that sends HTML emails. It worked well in Gmail, but I opened it in Outlook, it was all Chinese.

I learned about MIME emails - Sending 2 versions of the email, one with HTML and one plain text, but didn't understand how to create one. I saw somewhere that you need a certificate with a private key.

Can someone explain how to make it work?

This is my email-sending code:

```
'Send an email
strSMTPFrom = "Test@hp.com"
strSMTPTo = email             'Email taken from array
strSMTPRelay = "smtp1.hp.com"       
strTextBody = strContent      'Content taken from the template

Set oMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strSMTPRelay
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

oMessage.Subject = strSubject
oMessage.From = strSMTPFrom
oMessage.To = strSMTPTo
oMessage.HTMLBody = strTextBody
oMessage.Send
```

Comment: Your code works. The multipart foobar is automatically generated by assigning the content to the `HTMLBody` property. If the results are not as you expect, the problem is with the content you're trying to deliver. What is the value of `strTextBody`? How does the result look like in Outlook? And how do you want it to look like?

Comment: Oh ok... I'm trying to send a flyer which is in HTML format. I knew the problem with Outlook was in the code, but I thought if I'd send a multipart message, Outlook could identify the problems it was having and choose the plain text version.

Comment: Outlook (or rather the Internet Explorer component it utilizes) is merely rendering what's in the HTML part of your mail. If it doesn't come out right, you need to fix the content. That may include catering to IE quirks. If you want help with this, please answer the questions I've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It was the charset. The HTML had this in one of the  tags.
The charset was set to `Unicode`. When it came to the Email clients, it was changed to `UTF-8`.
Gmail was able to make it work but Outlook wasn't.

We sent an HTML email example we found online, and when we saw it worked we checked its charset, which was `windows-1255`.

We changed the  tag in our code and it worked!

Thank you once again though for the quick reply